# Why "admit" with T but "admissible" with SS?

Tags: pronunciation, spelling, suffixes, consonants

I just noticed that when the suffix -ible is added to "admi**t**", it becomes "admi**ss**ible" rather than "admi**tt**ible".

There are few other examples:

- "omi**t**" = "omi**ss**ible" not "omi**tt**ible".
- "permi**t**" = "permi**ss**ible"
- "transmi**t**" = "transmi**ss**ible"

These are words that end with **it** and have **ssi** in the suffixed forms. I didn't find other words that show the same pattern. Most **it** words don't have **ssi** forms in suffixed words.

Also as Maciej says:

- commit = commission
- emit = emission
- admit = admission

I know that S and T are both alveolar sounds (produced at alveolar ridge) but this relationship seems to be confusing. I googled a lot but didn't find anything helpful.

Does anyone know why the **t** changes to **ss** in these words?

Comment: admit -> admission, commit -> commission, emit -> emission, remit -> remission... The rule is that the -mit suffix changes to -mission, provided that the word in question has such a noun form. As for "why"... "Latin did it" is the best I can say.

Comment: Because Latin. That's why.